# Animating scroll not working inside iframe

Tags: jquery, asp.net, iframe

I have a parent page (default.aspx) that includes an iframe page (iframe.aspx)… jQuery animated scroll is working perfectly in iframe.aspx and not working in the parent page (default.aspx).

iframe.aspx page:

```
 <input type="button" onclick="scollWin();" value="Scroll up" />

 <div id="scrollToHere">
  Scroll to here
  </div>

  <script type="javascript">
     function scrollWin(){
     $('html,body').animate({
     scrollTop: $("#scrollToHere").offset().top
     }, 2000);
 }
 </script>
```

Working: when I click on the button, scrolling window smoothly working and it goes to the `div`.

Parent page (default.aspx):

```
<iframe id="iframebody" runat="server" src="iframe.aspx" style="width:900px;height:600px"></iframe>
```

When I run the default.aspx page and click on the button, the scroll is not working.

Can you tell me how to access the parent scroll window?

Comment: @sagivo-->when i click on the button, the parent page(default.aspx) scroll is not working,,

Comment: Sagivo-->Frd i didn't get any error, my prob is scroll down is not working,,,the function is working in Iframe.aspx page not in default.aspx Refer this [link](http://blog.freelancer-id.com/2009/03/26/scroll-window-smoothly-in-jquery/)

Answer (score 0):

When i get this right the Script is inside the Iframe.aspx?
Then you should define another jscript function in the default.aspx which is  then called:

```
 <input type="button" onclick="parent.scollWin();" value="Scroll up" />
```

Another Option: Have you tried to use jQUery Plugin ScrollTo?

[ScrollTo](http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/ScrollTo)

Comment: --> dude it's not working, can you give me some other example??

Comment: if you are inside the default.aspx and want to do some javascript then the function should be declared inside the default.aspx. If you want to call this function from your iframe you have to use "parent." infront of the function-name!

Comment: in the code you posted you use "scollWin();" and your function is called "scrollWin()", but i guess you sorted that out in your original code...

Comment: This seems to have done the trick! Parent window scroll is working now
           ' window.parent.$('html,body').animate'